# Limiting rows load using For Loop Container (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I got an SSIS exercise in my course.

The main function of the project is to join two tables and then load them into STG table. The trick is to limit the load of the rows to 5k only using For Loop Container.

I have built the ETL, but when I ran it, it seems that the For Loop Container is not addressing the Init,Eval and Assaign Expressions at all and loads the full table.

**This is how all the control flow looks like:**

http://prntscr.com/qac5f8

**variables:**

http://prntscr.com/qac6lh

**The task inside the For Loop Container:**

http://prntscr.com/qac65t

The row counter populates `@Rowcounter`.

**The definition of the Loop Container:**

http://prntscr.com/qac8ox

Where is the mistake? I assume that my logic regarding the For Loop is correct.

Comment: Using a `For Loop Container` to limit a load to 5k records certainly isn't the best way to utilize SSIS, but shouldn't be too complicated. Create a data flow that joins the tables together and puts the records in a work table. Then configure your `For Loop` to run 5k times. Then inside the loop, take the top 1 record from the work table and insert it into your STG table, then delete that record from the work table. Do this 4999 more times.

Comment: Hi Dale, Thanks for your answer.
This is part of a course exercise.
I basically did what you described...
As you can see, the for loop container, don't stop at 5K, but run all the table row. I defined an expression that will pause the for loop container, but it wouldn't.

Comment: It looks like you aren't taking the top 1 record inside your loop. Try changing your `Extract PreSTG SalesOrderDetail` source to be a query. Then use a `TOP 1` in your source query.